# Los datos que introduzco no se agregan a sus correspondientes listas. (Str e Int)

Tags: python

me gustaría que me ayudaran aquí, mi objetivo es que a partir de una lista con String y Enteros se muestre una lista con los Str y otra con los Int. El problema es que no sé por qué los datos no se agregan a sus correspondientes listas. Seguramente es una tontería pero no logro verlo.

Gracias de antemano!

```
lista_general = []
lista_enteros = []
lista_strings = []
dato_agregado = None

print("Para finalizar el código escriba Finalizar")

while not dato_agregado == "Finalizar":
    dato_agregado = input("Dime un número o una frase: ")
    if not dato_agregado == "Finalizar":
        lista_general.append(dato_agregado)
        print("Dato agregado")

for dato in lista_general:
    if dato == int:
        lista_enteros.append(dato)
    elif dato == str:
        lista_strings.append(dato)

print("Estos son los Strings: {} y estos son los Enteros: {}".format(lista_strings, lista_enteros))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error es que compruebas si el dato es "integro", no si el dato es UN dato integro. En python todo son objetos, y los tipos de dato son en realidad objetos instanciados de las clases bases int, str, etc.

**1:** De manera que para comprobar si una variable es una string o un integro, en realidad debes comprobar si son una instancia de esa clase base.

```
if isinstance(dato, int):
    lista_enteros.append(dato)
elif isinstance(dato, str):
    lista_strings.append(dato)
```

**2:** Otra alternativa sería usar el tipo, pero te dará errores con ciertas strings  como unicode literals.

```
if type(dato) == int:
    lista_enteros.append(dato)
elif type(dato) == str:
    lista_strings.append(dato)
```

Recomiendo la primera opción.

**Bonus:** Para hacer más facil de entender tus prints, si estás utilizando Python 3.6 o superior, las f-strings evitan el lio de tener que usar `format`.

```
print(f"Estos son los Strings: {lista_strings} y estos son los Enteros: {lista_enteros}")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y la aclaración, aunque aún sigo confundido con eso de los objetos y las instancias jaja. Hice lo que me dijiste la cosa es que el programa me devuelve esto: Estos son los Strings: ['hola', 'estar', '12', '8', '9'] y estos son los Enteros: []

Comment: Sí, eso es porque la manera de capturar datos de un input siempre es de strings. Deberías de convertir los datos a `int` si el valor es numerico, se puede facilmente con la función `isdigit()`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isdigit.asp

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
lista_general = []
lista_enteros = []
lista_strings = []
dato_agregado = ""

print("Para finalizar el código escriba Finalizar")

while not dato_agregado == "Finalizar":
    dato_agregado = input("Dime un número o una frase: ")
    if not dato_agregado == "Finalizar":
        lista_general.append(dato_agregado)
        print("Dato agregado")

for dato in lista_general:
    if dato.isdigit():
        lista_enteros.append(dato)

    elif isinstance (dato, str):
        lista_strings.append(dato)


print("Estos son los Strings: {} y estos son los Enteros: {}".format(lista_strings, lista_enteros))
```